# Building RAP with Tycho/Maven gives DuplicateReactorIUsException

Tags: java, maven, tycho, eclipse-rap

I'm on the hard way of getting Maven to compile my OSGi-based RAP application by the use of  Tycho. I think i'm nearly done glueing everything together, but then there's this one error i'm unable to fix, because i don't know, where it comes from. 
With any Maven command in the root of my working directory i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.DuplicateReactorIUsException: Duplicate reactor project IUs.
[ERROR] de.andre.osgitest 0.0.1.qualifier => [C:\eclipse\modeling\pomws\de.andre.osgitest, C:\eclipse\modeling\pomws\de.andre.osgitest.product]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.DuplicateReactorIUsException: Duplicate reactor project IUs.
de.andre.osgitest 0.0.1.qualifier => [C:\eclipse\modeling\pomws\de.andre.osgitest, C:\eclipse\modeling\pomws\de.andre.osgitest.product]

        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.DuplicateReactorIUsException: Duplicate reactor project IUs.
de.andre.osgitest 0.0.1.qualifier => [C:\eclipse\modeling\pomws\de.andre.osgitest, C:\eclipse\modeling\pomws\de.andre.osgitest.product]

        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.getPreliminaryReactorProjectUIs(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.manager.ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(P2DependencyResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:266)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        ... 11 more
```

The project structure is as follows:

```
root
|de.andre.osgitest
|  |src
|  |  | ...
|  |
|  |META-INF
|  |  | MANIFEST.MF
|  |
|  |OSGI-INF
|  |  | contribution.xml
|  |
|  |WEB-INF
|  |  | launch.ini
|  |  | web.xml
|  |
|  |- build.properties
|  |- de.andre.osgitest.launch
|  |- osgitest.target
|  |- pom.xml
|
|de.andre.osgitest.feature
|  |rootfiles
|  |  |lib
|  |  |  |- org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge_1.3.0.v20140430-1556.jar
|  |  |
|  |  |- launch.ini
|  |  |- web.xml
|  |
|  |- pom.xml
|  |- feature.xml
|  |- build.properties
|
|de.andre.osgitest.product
|  |- pom.xml
|  |- osgitest.product
|  |- assembly.xml
|
|- pom.xml
```

Because the pom.xml's are too much for this thread, i'll refer to http://pastebin.com/S7AM7hbW here.

I hope one of you bright ones has an idea.

Cheers, André

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to ensure that all `artifactId`s are unique (http://software.2206966.n2.nabble.com/Does-artifact-id-really-have-to-be-globally-unique-0-10-regression-td5630018.html).

I usually use this pattern:

```xml
<groupId>com.example.product</groupId> 
<artifactId>com.example.product.bundle1</artifactId>

<groupId>com.example.product</groupId> 
<artifactId>com.example.product.bundle2</artifactId>
```

where the `artifactId` matches the bundles `Bundle-SymbolicName`.

Comment: I already checked that and ensured, that all `artifactId`s are unique. My guess is, that Tycho internally generates reactors from the OSGi projects, hat have the same `artifactId`, but i don't know how to get rid of this. I already renamed all `artifactId`s, so that they don't overlap with any OSGi module's id.

Comment: But the error message lists two projects as having the same id: `de.andre.osgitest 0.0.1.qualifier => [C:\eclipse\modeling\pomws\de.andre.osgitest, C:\eclipse\modeling\pomws\de.andre.osgitest.product]`. If your ids are actually unique you may have encountered a bug, maybe [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392320)?

Comment: The description sounds very familiar to what i'm encountering, thank you. So for the reason the bug is open for more than 2 years now without a fix, i think i'll look out for another way to integrate maven.

Comment: Your setup appears to be fairly simple and it should be able to be built with Tycho just fine. No offences but I think the problem here lies on your side and ditching Tycho won't solve the root cause. Have you tried to use a known-to-work build as a template, e.g. the [RAP examples build](http://git.eclipse.org/c/rap/org.eclipse.rap.git/tree/releng/org.eclipse.rap.examples.build) or any other product-based Tycho build?

Comment: You're right. I used exactly this as a template for my build, but it won't work as expected. I would really like to investigate more time in solving the problem, but for now i have to move on to get some other projects ready. I'll come back in a few weeks, hoping to be able to solve the problem with a fresh mind.